# Why some example in tensor flow tutorial need to be compiled?

Tags: tensorflow

In some tensorflow tutorial (e.g RNN) the code need to be compiled with bazel. Why we have to compile these examples even they are written in python ?

Answer (score 0):

Because Python calls into C code using SWIG and that needs to be compiled